# How to visit the Russian State Duma in Moscow?

Tags: russia, moscow, government-buildings

During my next visit to Moscow I would like to visit the [Russian State Duma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_Duma). I am aware that it's [possible for Russian citizens](http://www.osd.ru/txtinf.asp?tx=3422) to visit the building, but what about foreigners?

If it's possible, I'd prefer to do it as a last-minute thing, rather than booking in advance. If it matters I do speak Russian, so it's okay if the tour is not English speaking.

Comment: Do you have journalist credentials?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tour you've linked made by [LDPR politic party](http://ldpr.ru/party/Ads/Excursions_in_the_State_Duma/) and this is only for a Russian citizens.

However, [here you can find](http://tourincity.ru/ru/ekskursii-po-moskve/ekskursiya-v-gosdumu) a tour description which is done for foreigners too, and, maybe, you can also select a language (description said that you can pickup any language, but I don't think that it's really "any" :)). You probably should try to cantact the agency by email, contact information can be found [here](http://tourincity.ru/en/kontakty).

> Contact information:
>
> Address: Moscow, Nikolskaya st., 4/5, office 389.
> Phones:
> +7 499 39 810 29
> +7 926 02 11 481
> E-mail: info@tourincity.ru, tourincity@yandex.ru
> SKYPE tourincity

**Update**: it appears as none of travel agencies can actually do this tour for now. Can't say why is that, but right now I can't find any way to get into that building with excursion.

Comment: I've dropped them an email, will post their reply here later.

Comment: Sadly, they no longer do this tour: https://i.imgur.com/R1iNGsd.png

Comment: Ok, still searching

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: @Psychonaut as I already wrote: Update: it appears as none of travel agencies can actually do this tour for now. Can't say why is that, but right now I can't find any way to get into that building with excursion.